# How to query in django view to add two numbers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to query in **view.py** such that I can display the sum of two integers input by the client. I can't seem to find a way on how to add numbers entered by client and display on server. Any suggestion on how to approach this problem will be real helpful. If any query related to question  please ask, I will try to make it clearer.

**Models.py::**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
class Addition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    int1 = models.IntegerField()
    int2 = models.IntegerField()
     **Edited Section**
    @property
    def total_score(self):
        total = self.int1+self.int2
        return total
```

**Form.py::**

```
from django import forms
from . models import Addition
class AdditionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Addition
        fields = [
            'name',
            'int1',
            'int2',
        ]
```

**Serializer.py::**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Addition, Subtraction
class AdditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Addition
        fields = '__all__'
```

**View.py::**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404,render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from . forms import AdditionForm
from . models import Addition
from . serializers import AdditionSerializer
from .forms import SubtractionForm
from . models import Subtraction
from . serializers import SubtractionSerializer

class AdditionList(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        additions = Addition.objects.all()
        serializer = AdditionSerializer(additions,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
class AdditionListForm(APIView):
    def post(request):
        form = AdditionForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form =AdditionForm()
        return render(request,'add/addition_form.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Also I tried with this method in Model.py but I couldn't find a way on how to display it or use in view.

    @property
        def total_score(self):
            total = self.int1+self.int2
            return total

Comment: It's not obvious what you're asking for. Also, setting `default=True` on `IntegerField` is really bad - even if that works, `True` will evaluate to 1, so the default value will be always "one" and possibly that's not what you expected.

Comment: Do you want to add all numbers in `Addition` modal or you have to add an only the latest number which is entered by user?

Comment: Why on earth are you using DRF for a plain view, and why are you using a model and modelform for this ???

Comment: @Charnel I've removed the default settings on IntegerField. I want to add int1 and int2 in model and display it on server in JSON format.

Comment: @MKPatel I want to add number as user enters  and display it.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sorry what is DRF? I'm using model i'm defining the fieldtype and ModelForm is created so User can enter their own number. Is it clear?

Comment: But for that why you are using Django rest framework. For that simple use, you have to use `view` only.

Comment: @Ajax DRF = [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). You know, the thing you import serializers and APIViews from ? This is not part of Django, and not needed for plain http / html requests. Neither are models nor modelforms here FWIW, you just need a plain Django form and basic maths here.

Comment: @MKPatel my task was to create an api where there are two integers and store it in db retrieve from that db add the result and output the result. Also create an template from where user can enter two integer gets stored in db and calculation is performed in background and gives the sum of those integers in JSON format. So this is the approach that I went with, is my approach correct or should I approach in any other way?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers please read my above comment why I went with this approach. In what way should I approach this problem if you could suggest me, would really be helpful

Comment: @ajax well if those are the requirements then your code makes more sense indeed.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  So only part that I'm stuck with is how to add the numbers and display only the total of that sum. So could you please tell me should I add it in the Models.py or should I perform it in view.py or /and in what way? Because basic int1+int2 doesnot work here, so what could be done?

Comment: @Ajax according to your requirements - which I assume are kind of homework or test, else they wouldn't make sense -, "calculation is performed in background". What does this "in background" really mean here ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers basically I want to add the numbers that user inputs

Comment: @Ajax yes I think we all understood that xD - what I mean is that in this context, "in background" could imply some out of band operation (async task queue). This could be the case If the goal is to teach you how to put a full rest API / DB storage / async computations stack or assess your ability to do so. That's why I asked if there where more details on those points in your requirements. Also since this is clearly homework of some kind, I'm not going to answer with a complete solution ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ahaha... well this is kind of an homework only so I could learn working  of REST API using django. I would also like not to get the solution but asking the approach or from somewhere I can refer to. like should I work on model or view to get the desired result? Any help or suggestion will be helpful. P.S.:: I'm self learning so I've got no other individual to ask to.

Comment: @Ajax ok I get the point ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  I have made some changes to model.py...see if it works i have mentioned change in your thread's comment...please can you look for it once and see if it's better approach as I see view is not a good method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210277/discussion-between-ajax-and-bruno-desthuilliers).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers if you could please suggest me whether the edit code is appropriate or not?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "where should I do the addition", there's no "purely technical" answer - it's technically legal and valid to put this in your view, in your form, in your serializer, in your model, or even in a distinct function in a 3rd part package if you want.

BUT there *is* a clear answer from design POV. A well structured app [separates the domain layer from the UI](https://proandroiddev.com/multiple-ways-of-defining-clean-architecture-layers-bbb70afa5d4a) - the domain layer should NOT depend on the UI.

In Django, the UI is composed of the views / serializers (if you build a REST api) / templates / forms, and the domain layer is mostly tied to the data access layer in models (not necessarily in the `Model` classes though - some part are better implemented as standalone functions or classes).

IOW, in your case, providing the addition's result is clearly a responsability of your `Addition` model. This doesn't mean you should add a `result` database field to your model (this would break relational model normalization rules), just add a `get_result(self)` method (or, since the operation here is quite cheap, a `result` `property`). You'll of course have to customize your serializer etc to return this result with your data.

NB : you could also use Django's orm annotations to delegate the addition to your database (RDBMs are not jsut for data storage, they can do quite a few operations on your data, and most often much quicker than pure Python code). This is of course a bit overkill here but since this is a toy learning project, you may want to try this too for educational purpose.

As a general guideline: your domain layer should provide all the domain logic and know nothing of the UI layer, so you can use it with different UIs (traditional http/html UI, rest API, command line scripts, native GUI, whatever), and the UI should only handle presentation / user interaction logic and delegate everything else to the domain.

Comment: I really appreciate you for your guidance.  I will definitely follow with your suggestions and try my best to develop project with this method only...:-)

Comment: from django.db import models
    from django.conf import settings
    class Addition(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        int1 = models.IntegerField()
        int2 = models.IntegerField()
        # total = models.IntegerField()
        @property
        def total_score(self):
            # return self.int1 + self.int2
            total = self.int1+self.int2
            return total

I want to add this total to my database say int3 = models.intergerField.

is this method a good way to approach because i'm not sure which one is domain layer

Comment: @Ajax code in comments is unreadable. Edit your question instead (leaving the existing code, just adding your new code at then end with explanations). Just a hint though: re-read my answer more carefully.